# eclipse PDT: How to enable content/code assist for personal PHP libraries

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, doctrine, eclipse-pdt

I am struggeling getting content/code assist to work for PHP libraries (other than Zend) in my Zend Framework project folder:

- library

  - Doctrine
  - Zend (<-works with code assist...)
  - ZendX

Content assist remains blank when using this libraries...

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Udo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content Assist is available for any compatible resources in the include path.

Right click your project folder. Then *Include Path*. Then *Configure Include Path*. A window will appear. Configure any needed resources.

Further Information in the Zend Studio Manual:

- [Adding Elements to a Project Include Path](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/zend-studio.htm#adding_elements_to_a_project_s_include_path.htm)
- [Include Paths](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/zend-studio.htm#include_paths.htm)
- [Code Assist Concept](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/zend-studio.htm#code_assist_concept.htm)

Comment: perfect, thanks! any idea how to define the path separator? the code assist window displays "Doctrine\Common" -> should be "Doctrine_Common"...

Comment: @udo I'm not sure but it seems it's showing namespaces then. Cant check how to change that right now unfortunately. I'll have to ask to check with the docs. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful for some one, I am using eclipse kepler, and I did not find Include_path variable. If you have same probleme as me, right click on the project and select configure then add php support. This will add php include path to your properties option. Then chose php include path and in the libraries folder add zend library location.