# adding existing zend framework directory to eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework

I am new to php. I was reading a book and created a sample project using the zend framework. My app is in C:\apache\htdocs\mysite.com\

I want to add this to eclipse project explorer. I dont see an option to open existing project in eclipse. How can I do this?

Also after I have added the project do I need to add the library directory from zend framework somewhere in my project references so that eclipse knows to include this?

Would eclipse intellisense pick up the new library or do I need to add a plugin?

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: For the first question, file > import > existing folder as new project

Comment: I dont see an option to import existing folder. There is just one option in File->Import->General->Import existing project which does not work when I add the directory as it cannot find any projects in there

Comment: Do you see an option similar to "Create new project from existing directory"?  I use Zend Studio (based on Eclipse) which has this option and that is what I do in your situation.

Comment: File->New Project->New PHP Project->Create project at existing location (from existing source)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Create new project from existing source

** screenshots are provided below*

1. File > New > Project... `screenshot-1`
2. Select "PHP / PHP Project" > Next `[screenshot-2]`
3. Select "Create project at existing location (from existing source)" -- add the directory of your project. i.e. select "Browse..." and browse to the folder where your project is *(e.g. in your case the directory is "C:\apache\htdocs\mysite.com\")* `[screenshot-3]`
4. Select "Finish" your done.

### Add Zend Framework for code completion

See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903769/how-do-you-add-a-php-framework-to-code-completion-assist-in-eclipse-pdt-and-can) stackoverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039712/eclipse-pdt-how-to-enable-content-code-assist-for-personal-php-libraries).

Also see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981956/whats-the-difference-between-the-build-path-and-the-include-path-in-eclipse-pdt) on the difference between the build path and the include path.

### Screenshots

`screenshot-1`

[image]

`screenshot-2`

[image]

`screenshot-3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your personal project structure (including your web server) and project structures in Eclipse are independent structures. Eclipse has no way of knowing what your "personal" projects are.

You should have PDT installed in Eclipse and then in Project Explorer create New->PHP Project. In contents you will have to select "Create project at existing location (from existing source)" where you can select your project's folder.

Follow the wizard in case you have to add libraries, this can be a little tricky if they are outside the project.